# Do "significant" and "surge" collocate well?

Tags: collocations

Are the following sentences natural?

> 1. Prices significantly surged.
> 2. There has been a significant surge in prices.

In google search I found 612000 results that seems enough to accept this as a valid collocation, but in [Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary](https://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=surge) I couldn't find "significant surge". There are other adjectives such as dramatic, great and sudden but nothing about "significant"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you mean "collocate". You may mean "are natural and idiomatic when used together" or maybe "can be used together".

The two words are not a natural pair. If you're after totally idiomatic language, then no.

On the other hand, the words do fit together grammatically and semantically, so if you're purposefully avoiding cliché collocations (IMO "surged dramatically" is cliché), and you precisely mean "significantly" in contrast with "trivially", then they're fine together.

Also, "Prices surged significantly" is a more natural word order.

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine. I suspect 1. would often occur as "prices surged significantly". Even if some/many usage guides say the adverb should precede the verb, a lot of time I find that the adverb follows verb in both written and spoken use.

Comment: +1 for a good answer and a funny user name :)